# Want to store output from itertools as array

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following code

```
result = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(3),3)

for each in result:
    print(each)
```

with output:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2)
```

I want to store the individual "items" in "result" as an numpy arrays if they sum up to lets say 2. I'm not sure exactly what data type itertools outputs.

Example in pseudo code:

```
for each in result:
    if sum(each)==2:
        numpy array = each
```

Comment: You can always check type of output in python by `type(output)`. it is tuple in your case.

Comment: `[(x, y, z) for (x,y,z) in result if x + y + z == 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use the comprehension:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

result = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(3),3)
desired = [np.array(i) for i in result if sum(i)==2]
desired
#[array([0, 0, 2]), array([0, 1, 1])]
```

Comment: I can't acess it? desired[0][0] gives me index out of range.

Comment: neither desired[0] for that matter, if its a list with two arrays in it

Comment: Did you use 2? If you did there should be 2 arrays

Comment: yes! Thats what I dont get. The itertools should return an object list of tuples. Your code should store these tuples as arrays in another list, called desired. I should be able to acess the array via brackets but it is empty. I suspect that the condition is wrong i.e. the sum(i)==2 does not return anything.

Comment: I tested this on both python 2 and 3 and it works. Do you use different array instead of `range(3)`?

Comment: yes I use np.arange(3) but it didn't matter. Still index out of range

Comment: It prints out "0"?

Comment: Yes, it's the first element of first array. Remove the indices with `print(desired)` and you'll get your arrays.

Comment: Ok, I copied your code itno my IDE and now it works, must have been something weird there. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional solution:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

result = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(3),3)

list(map(np.array, filter(lambda x: sum(x)==2, result)))

# [array([0, 0, 2]), array([0, 1, 1])]
```